# Problem in register activation hook and Copying folder

Tags: hooks, user-registration

Hy Guys, I am wanting to copy a folder to activate my plugin, I'm trying this but it does not work.

```
function hyperbolic_activate() {

    $src = 'includes/myTheme/';
    $dst = '../themes/';

    function recurs_copy($src,$dst) {
        $dir = opendir($src);
        @mkdir($dst);
        while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) {
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) {
            if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) {
                recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file);
            } else {
                copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
    }
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'hyperbolic_activate' );
```

What is the problem in my code?

Comment: Please turn on debugging and tell us what "it does not work" exactly is.

Comment: Simply it does not copy the folder '/mytheme/' for the directory indicated.

Comment: No. What your Error message is. And where it is coming from.

Comment: I solved the problem with the following code: http://pastebin.com/fVPKQRLB

Comment: Please, add that code in separate answer, not as a pastebin in a comment.

Comment: "Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer in 4 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead." I'll post later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining the recurs_copy() function to perform the copy but you never execute it. Try:

```
function hyperbolic_activate() {

   $src = 'includes/myTheme/';
   $dst = '../themes/';
   recurs_copy($src, $dst);

}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'hyperbolic_activate' );

function recurs_copy($src,$dst) {
    $dir = opendir($src);
    @mkdir($dst);
    while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) {
      if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) {
         if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) {
            recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file);
         } else {
            copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file);
         }
      }
    }
   closedir($dir);
 }
```

Comment: This generated a series of errors, 'Could not be activated because it generated a fatal error.', there were so many mistakes that neither of to spend here.

Comment: Check the path to the folder you are trying to copy and the destination.

Comment: You should mark my answer as the correct one. I've seen your solution and it is the code I posted with the correct paths to the directories (as I did suggest you to check). Thank you.